# "to think my country is at the first place."

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, idioms, expressions

I happened to find a chart showing a rank of countries based on their frequent use of VPNs.

Someone wrote "to think my country is at the first place." (and this was the only sentence he wrote)

What does this really mean? (It seems that the "commenter" was surprised by the fact) Is this a common expression in English?

I have tried Googling this, and found nothing.
I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: I think it's common enough to readily be understood and your understanding of the context is correct. It's mostly surprise with likely some disgust mixed in with it.

Comment: @Ghost To think it's not a common expression to my ears. Thank you though. I'm not a regular English user by the way.

Comment: Note that although *To think [statement]* is a common way of expressing the fact that the speaker finds *[statement]* surprising, the specific statement in this example *(my country is at the first place)* is completely non-idiomatic and/or ungrammatical. The exact context might make a difference, but in *most* situations, *my country is **in** first place* is probably how it would be phrased *(my country is in the lead / in front / winning / etc.)*. (Also note that in practice, *any* such statement would almost certainly end with an **exclamation mark!** :)